# Difference between JAVA_OPTS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS?

Tags: java

When should each of these environment variables be used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between \_JAVA\_OPTIONS JAVA\_TOOL\_OPTIONS and JAVA\_OPTS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28327620/difference-between-java-options-java-tool-options-and-java-opts)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

see ["what is" doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#whatIs) and ["tool options" doc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jvmti/jvmti.html#tooloptions)

Basically, the `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is intended for use by development tools, monitoring tools and the like whereas `JAVA_OPTS` is used for running 'general' Java programs, I think people tend to mix and match somewhat (from what Google has shown me example wise).

Comment: One real-world example: JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is used by TeamCity CI to pass settings to step runners such as "Simple Build Tool" (Scala SBT), and users need use JAVA_OPTS in order to not clobber the implicit system parameters passed on by the TeamCity server such as - http_proxy could be one of these.

Comment: Another difference is that when JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is defined, a message is always echoed to stdout, like `Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -XX:+UseG1GC -Xmx4G`.

Comment: If it's of value for readers using later JVMs, those links above can be found also for [java 17](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/jvmti.html#tooloptions) or [java 11](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#tooloptions).

Answer (score 20):

`JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS` is read by some JDK tools, but has limited applicability.

`JAVA_OPTS` is a convention used by Apache Tomcat and some other apps, but is not
read directly by any JDK tools published by Sun/Oracle, AFAIK.

From:
https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=6438415

> JAVA_OPTS is not an environment variable that the java executable will
>   recognize on it's own. Instead, various scripts which wrap the start
>   up of java will often use an environment variable named JAVA_OPTS to
>   configure the java executable (for example, the tomcat startup script
>   does this).