# Specifying default character set encoding for Java

Tags: java, linux, spring, tomcat, jvm

I want my Spring Boot application to use default charset `CP866`. So, during Tomcat startup, I added the following in Environment variable:

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS=-Dfile.encoding=CP866
```

Still, it seems the change is not in effect, the application is not using `CP866` as the default charset.
Also, when I see Java properties using `java -XshowSettings`, it still shows:  `file.encoding = UTF-8`

Please share if you have any idea how to achieve the change?

Note: after migrating from a new server, in my app, an image/photo update feature is not working properly. I sense this is because of encoding issue on the new system. In the previous server, the file.encoding was `CP866`.
I don't prefer any code change for the new server.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot embedded or standalone Tomcat server? How do you deploy/start your application? This also could be useful for you:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3933300/difference-between-java-opts-and-java-tool-options

Comment: I am using Tomcat. I deploy my application as an WAR file using Tomcat manager. I tried both JAVA_OPTS and JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS in Tomcat startup script. However, nothing helped.

Comment: Can you please check this:

1. stop Tomcat  
2. define the environment variable in the console:  
`export JAVA_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=CP866`  
3. start Tomcat  
4. verify that encoding configuration is applied during Tomcat startup
`ps -ef | grep tomcat | grep file.encoding`  

There should be output something like that:  
/usr/local/java/bin/java .. **-Dfile.encoding=CP866** ... -Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/ilya/Downloads/apache-tomcat-8.5.50/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start  If you see -Dfile.encoding=CP866 in your output now you can deploy your application.

Comment: Exactly how @IlyaLapitan writes - you do need to use `JAVA_OPTS`. And it would help if you share how exactly you startup your Tomcat (via `tomcat/bin/startup.sh`? not from an IDE?) and your configuration script where you put the `JAVA_OPTS=...` line(s).